# Elasticsearch is from faster then gte when working with dates

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, elasticsearch

I am using ES for my Laravel app.

I have mapped a date as:

```
'type' => 'date',
'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
```

Now I want to filter out dates that are equal to now() or more = I dont want to show any old dates.

I can do this two ways with a filter:

```
[ 'range' => [
  'end_date' => [ 'gte' => 'now' ]
]
],
```

or

```
[ 'range' => [
  'end_date' => [ 'from' => 'now' ]
]
],
```

**My question now is which one is faster/better?**

Using `'gte' => 'now'` or `'from' => 'now'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [RangeFilterParser](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/RangeFilterParser.java) sources, this is the exact same thing : you should not notice any difference between the use of `gte` and `from`.